# If a statement holds for all standard models of PA, then does it hold for all models?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, peano-axioms

Suppose that $\varphi$ is a consequence of every standard model of PA. Then is it provable from PA?

Comment: Standard examples of sentences $\varphi$ showing that this is not the case: $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$, "Hercules wins the Hercules-Hydra game", $\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}+$"there is a measurable cardinal"$)$, etc.

Comment: More interesting is to ask whether if a statement holds in all *nonstandard* models of $\mathsf{PA}$, then it also holds in the standard model. (And yes, that's the case.)

Comment: @Andres: (... trivially, because thanks to the upward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem some of the nonstandard models are elementarily equivalent to the standard one) :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is (up to isomorphism) only one standard model of PA. And there are sentences  true in the natural numbers that are not theorems of PA.

Comment: Is the 2nd part a hint at Goedel's theorem?

Comment: Yes, the theorem on the Incompleteness of PA is being referred to.